# NHD's description of a river differs depending on which state it is in

Tags: united-states, nhd

So I downloaded the [NHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Hydrography_Dataset) shapefiles for both Texas and Arkansas rivers from here:

https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Hydrography/NHD/State/Shape/

I then pulled the route of the [Sulfur River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulphur_River) from both of them. Even tho the the river flows through both Texas and Arkansas both states shapefiles depict stretches of the river flowing in the other state. But while the Texas one shows what appears to be a contiguous river the Arkansas one doesn't.

Here's the route of the Sulfur River in the Arkansas Shapefile:

[image]

Here's the route of the Sulfur River in the Texas shapefile:

[image]

The Texas one doesn't have gaps but the Arkansas one does. In fact, if you add up the lengths of the segments, the Texas one has ~175mi of (seemingly contiguous) river segments whereas the Arkansas one has ~110mi of (non contiguous) river segments.

Any ideas as to what's up with this?